# Entered trade to buy 500 sh at 57.06 aon stock traded at 56 but no execution broker said aon prevented execution can this happen?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, broker

This was a NYSE trade placed with brokerage firm. I placed a bid of 57.06 for 500 shares, all or none (AON), of a stock and it apparently traded at 56 without filling my bid. Broker checked with home office and reported findings to me that the AON condition prevented the execution of my bid even though it was more than a point higher than some of the trades? How did this happen?

Comment: Can you tag with your location and clarify which currency you placed the order in? AON seems to be trading at around USD86, which would be ~GBP51 or ~EUR63. Or are we talking about a different company or currency?

Comment: @RickGoldstein Perhaps by "AON" the OP is referring to the order type "all or none".

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea D'oh! Didn't even occur to me, but you're probably right. In that case, isn't the answer embedded in that fact? If there weren't enough shares available at the offer price, wouldn't that imply the "none" side of "all or none"?

Comment: And now we wait for someone to post an answer with "Yes"

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I have "fleshed out" the question and wonder if it can be reopened in its current form.

Answer (score 5):

All or nothing orders are dying out because of the prevalence of this eventuality.

Considering how high your bid was versus the last trade, this is a very illiquid equity.

For such an equity, it's unlikely that one side of the book will even have 500 shares available at any one time, and half are at unreasonable distances from the mid, so 500 shares will most likely not be filled at one time.

To trade such large amounts of such an illiquid security, it's best to remove the all or nothing restriction and allow other traders to pick at it for to satisfy their various intents.

Comment: Conversely, my fear of *not* using AON on an illiquid stock, especially if it was selling at a low price, is that I would get filled just enough to get charged the brokerage commission, but not enough for it to be worth my while.

Comment: @Michael and this actually did happen to me once many years ago... got a fill for 100 shares on a non-AON order, couldn't get any more shares at a decent price... some time later the stock reverse-split 1 for 25, so now I have 4 shares (which at the time IIRC was an extra cost to trade) so basically i lost nearly everything i put into that trade just in transaction costs.